# Store slice of 3D Numpy Array as a variable

Tags: python, numpy

I've got various 3D arrays that I'm viewing 2D slices of, along either the X, Y or Z axis.

To simplify my code, I would like to have one location of declaring the slice such as

```
# X View
my_view = [10, :, :] 
# Y View
# my_view = [:, 4, :] 
# Z View
# my_view = [:, :, 7]
```

and choose which view to run in my script.

Then the rest of my code can apply the myview slice when visualizing,

```
plt.plot(my_data[myview])
plt.plot(more_data[myview])
```

There's no way to "store" the ':' portion of the slice. How would I accomplish this in Python/Numpy?

Comment: `myview=(4, slice(None), slice(None))` etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`np.s_` is a handy tool for making an indexing tuple:

```
In [21]: np.s_[10,:,:]
Out[21]: (10, slice(None, None, None), slice(None, None, None))
```

but you can create that directly:

```
In [22]: (10,slice(None),slice(None))
Out[22]: (10, slice(None, None, None), slice(None, None, None))
```

`arr[i,j]` is the same as `arr[(i,j)]`, the comma creates a tuple.

```
In [23]: 10,slice(None),slice(None)
Out[23]: (10, slice(None, None, None), slice(None, None, None))
```

You can create a more general indexing tuple this way.

Answer (score 0):

Why not make `my_view` a function?

```py
def my_view(arr):
    """Returns a certain 2d slice of a 3d NumPy array."""
    # X View
    return arr[10, :, :] 
    # Y View
    # return arr[:, 4, :] 
    # Z View
    # return arr[:, :, 7]
```

Application:

```py
plt.plot(my_view(my_data))
plt.plot(my_view(more_data))
```